# When buying parts with serial interfaces is it useful to check timing requirements?

Tags: i2c, serial, timing

When buying parts with serial interfaces is it useful to check timing requirements? I'm especially curious about something like I2C; is it generally enough to see that a component is capable of communicating at 100 kHz or should one check each of the timing parameters and check that it works?

Comment: Are you asking if it is necessary to check the specifications the manufacturer have guaranteed? Not unless you have a good reason to believe these are off. Or when you are a party with some strict regulations requiring double-checking everything for compliance (such as military/government/aerospace/medical organizations)

Comment: It depends what are your requirements. If there is only one chip that does what you want so you must use it, what difference does it make what timings it has as long as you can communicate with it.

Comment: If you understand what "timing" is, then you wouldn't ask the question, right? The answer, not an opinion, is: It is useful to know what "timing" is, before checking timing requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I worked with an ADC that was assumed to be SPI interface, occasional missed bits led careful study of the timing diagram which actually indicated it was a prototypical serial interface that predates SPI and required a different polarity to execute the read vs the write command when using the standard SPI master.

One of the challenges of a "pseudo standard" like many serial interfaces is that some manufacturers may take liberties, either due to legacy or for a specific customers. In these cases it may be worthwhile to confirm via testing that the device works.

A "true" standard like USB or Ethernet , you can expect that a device that says "compliant" will work without any question.

However this is not too bad, these devices are simple and It is not too difficult to buy the part already mounted on a board as a sample. Practically every interesting IC out there has a breakout board someone is offering for sale.

If the testing shows off behavior then you will have to examine the timing diagram to see if you can understand where the issue lies.

Comment: SPI is more problematic than I2C, for which there is a specification document from the original manufacturer ... searching "UM10204" will easily find it.

Comment: Certainly, but what portion of i2c advertised devices actually follow or certify to the spec?

Comment: All serial interfaces predate SPI. SPI was just the name for the first ever MCU peripheral that was configurable and oriented to transfer bytes over a synchronous serial interface. So having a clocked serial interface does not mean you can use it with SPI peripheral with simple init and then just transfer bytes. I2C devices have their special quirks too.

Comment: @crasic I can't put a figure on it though anecdotally it seems to be a higher number, and I don't know anyone taking the diabolical liberties that (say) Analog Devices do (or did) with SPI. The specification raises at least the hypothetical possibility of Philips/NXP enforcing their trademark in court against non-compliant devices though I don't know it has ever happened.

Comment: All valid and good points thanks @user_1818839

Answer (score 0):

For I2C you do not have to check (mostly) because there is a specification. As mentioned in the comments. Search for the specification file "UM10204 pdf" and you'll find it. Remember that I2C works at 100kHz, 400kHz and some devices go higher. Most devices that advertise I2C follow the specification but like anything in life there are outliers. You can be mostly confident that the major manufacturers do follow the specification.

SPI is a different thing because there is no specification. Make sure the "options" (clock, sampling time, etc.) are supported by the devices you are using.

Comment: Not true that you don't need to check I2C devices. I bought some TC74 temperature sensors that were advertised as I2C, but there was one critical timing parameter (data hold time) that they did not meet. They work with an Arduino but not with other processors.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson, yab! Once apple mac did not have right timing (sh..) for their SMBUS. h h. It happens, while it appears working fine.

Comment: @jay Just to be clear, these sensors **did not** "work fine" with an I2C-compliant controller.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson, I understand.